# how to create java methods

Tags: java, methods

Create a class studentBilling() that includes three return overloaded calculateBill() methods as follows:

The first calculateBill() method will receive the tuition fees as single parameter. Add 14% tax to the tuition fees and return the total due.

The second calculateBill() method receives the tuition fees and the cost of textbooks. Add the two values and then add 14% tax and return the total due.

The third calculateBill() method receives the tuition fees, textbook costs and a coupon value. Add the tuition and cost of textbooks and subtract the coupon value. Add 14% tax and return the total due.

- Write a program billTesting that tests all three overloaded methods.
- Create a new studentBilling object.
- Create a Scanner object to enter the tuition fees, textbook costs, and the coupon value.
- Call the three methods and display the results.

my solution

```
package student;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author FASA
 */
public class Student {

      double totalDue;
      static Scanner fees = new Scanner(System.in);
      double Student;


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fees = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(CalculateBill1());
        System.out.println(CalculateBill2());
        System.out.println(CalculateBill3());
    }



    public static double CalculateBill1 (double totalDue, double tax, double fees) {

        tax = 0.14;
        return (totalDue);
    }    
    public double CalculateBill2 (double fees, double textBookFees) {
        double tax = 0.14;
        Student = fees + textBookFees + tax;
        return (totalDue);
    }
    public double  CalculateBill3 (double tax, double fees, double textBookFees, double couponValue) {

        Student = fees + textBookFees - couponValue + tax;
        return (totalDue);
    }    

}
```

It wont print the bill, please help

Comment: This is the time of year when we at Stack Overflow want to remind you that **we don't do people's homework here**.  [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). 

From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: but I'm learning java and this is giving me errors, you could have said that I should look at my statements instead of giving me a hard lecture, you were once a learner too remember and you had your ways of learning

Comment: You need to show the errors you are getting. That's part of describing the difficulty you are having

Comment: the 3 methods wont print in my main method I'm using netbeans@Chrisis

Comment: Your `calculateBill...` methods (which, by the way, are **not** overloaded) require arguments to be passed, and you're not passing any when calling them in your `main`.  There should be compiler errors displayed which  tell you that.  Look for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to help you with the complete solution as it seems to be your homework ;)

You should get compilation error on lines `System.out.println(CalculateBill1());
        System.out.println(CalculateBill2());
        System.out.println(CalculateBill3());` because there is no method with definition as void parameter.

you need to pass appropriate parameters to call these methods. For example to call method "CalculateBill1 (double totalDue, double tax, double fees)" you need to call it like below:

```
System.out.println(CalculateBill1(1.25,5.23,6.0));
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks @Shubhendu I appreciate it